# Ito Stochastic Differential Equation Construction

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-differential-equations

How do you construct an Ito Differential Equation with solution $Y_p$, where $p \in  \mathbb{Z}+$ and
$Y_p = (X(t) - \mathbb{E}(X(t)))^p$

Where $X(t)$ is the Ornstein- Uhlenbeck process, i.e

$dX = - \gamma X dt + \sigma dW$

and

$X(t) = \exp(-\gamma t)X(0) + \sigma \int_{0}^{t} \exp (-\gamma (t-s)) dW(s)$

I know that

$\mathbb{E}(X(t)) = X(0)\exp(-\gamma t)$

and so

$\lim\limits_{t \to \infty} \mathbb{E}(X(t)) = 0$

I'm just not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Since you know that $\mathbb{E}[X(t)] = X(0)\exp(-\gamma t)$, you can write $Y_p = f(t,X_t)$ with $$ f(t,x) = \left(x-X(0)\exp(-\gamma t)\right)^p$$ and apply Itô's lemma.

Comment: Would $X(t) - \mathbb{E} (X(t))$ not equal $\sigma \int_{0}^{t} \exp (-\gamma (t-s)) dW(s)$?

Comment: Yes that is true, in fact it's probably much simpler to apply Itô's lemma with this process instead

Comment: I'm having difficulty applying the lemma, would you be able to give me more guidance?

Answer (score 3):

Let $Z(t) := \sigma \int_{0}^{t} \exp (-\gamma (t-s)) dW(s)$. We have $Y_p(t) = Z(t)^p$ and we want to find the SDE solved by $Y_p$.

Clearly, $Z(t)$ is a driftless OU-process, i.e. it is a solution of the SDE
$$dZ(t) = - \gamma Z(t) dt + \sigma dW(t),\quad Z(0) = 0 $$

[Itô's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4%27s_lemma) applied to $Y_p(t) = f(t,Z(t))$ with $f(t,x) := x^p$ yields
\begin{align}
dY_p(t) =df(t,Z(t)) &= 0\times dt + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(t,Z_t)dZ(t) + \frac 1 2\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}(t,Z_t)dt\\
&=pZ(t)^{p-1}dZ(t) + \frac{p(p-1)}{2}Z(t)^{p-2} dt\\
&=\left[-\gamma p Z(t)^p+ \frac{p(p-1)}{2}Z(t)^{p-2}\right]dt + \sigma p Z(t)^{p-1}dW(t)
\end{align}

Finally, if we recall that $Z(t) = Y_p(t)^{1/p}$, we find that $Y_p(t)$ is solution of
$$dY_p(t) = \left[-\gamma p Y_p(t)+ \frac{p(p-1)}{2}Y_p(t)^{(p-2)/p}\right]dt + \sigma p Y_p(t)^{(p-1)/p}dW(t)$$